# knex subquery with union and limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to do the following query:

```
select *
from A
where id in (
    (select id from A where created_at >= '2018-12-25' order by created_at asc limit 1)
    union
    (select id from A where created_at < '2018-12-26' order by created_at desc limit 1)
)
```

What I've tried with knex was:

```
knex.select('*')
  .from('A')
  .whereIn('id', qb => 
    qb.select('*')
      .from('A')
      .where('created_at', '>=', '2018-12-25')
      .orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
      .limit(1)
      .union(qb =>
        qb.select('*')
          .from('A')
          .where('created_at', '<', '2018-12-26')
          .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
          .limit(1)
      )
  )
```

But it yields different SQL:

```
select *
from "A"
where "id" in (select * from "A" where "created_at" >= ? union select * from "A" where "created_at" < ? order by "created_at" DESC limit ? order by "created_at" ASC limit ?)
```

Seems like `order by` clauses are not processed in the way I want, also, parentheses groups are not the same. What is my mistake here? How do I do it right with knex?

Comment: Does the union is really useful ?

Comment: @DanielE. Well, if you have ideas how to refactor it to get the same result, those would be appreciated as well, but my initial idea was to select * from list of ids which is a result of two subqueries, unified with union, which yield id of the first item, created on a given a day and id of the last item, created on a given day. Even if I can do it without union I'd be glad to know what do I miss here

Comment: Could you please illustrate the suggested usage? If I understood you correct that would output all the rows, created within the interval, while I need only 2 - first and last

Comment: I know sql but not knex.js, my answer may be out of the question

Comment: Yeah, I know how to query what I want here with raw sql, the whole question is about doing that with knex

Answer (score 1):

Following will output your desired sql but I guess its not the efficient ways to doing thing.

```js
const sql = knex
  .select('*')
  .from('A')
  .whereIn('id', (qb) =>
    qb
      .union((qb) =>
        qb
          .select('id')
          .from('A')
          .where('created_at', '>=', '2018-12-25')
          .orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
          .limit(1)
      )
      .union(
        (qb) =>
          qb
            .select('id')
            .from('A')
            .where('created_at', '<', '2018-12-26')
            .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            .limit(1),
        false
      )
  )
  .toSQL();
console.log(sql);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What would you advice as a more efficient way?

Comment: That depends on your database structure.